# Cannot connect to MQTT server: "Reason code: 5 - Not authorized to perform the requested operation"

Tags: java, server, mqtt, message, paho

- The task: send "Hello world" to server for test.
- Server: clouldMQTT.
- Lib: PahoMQTT.
- Reason code: 5 - Not authorized to perform the requested operation.
- Cause: null.
- Message code: No connection permissions.
- Code:

  ```
  String topic    = "Lesson_MQTT_server";
  String broker   = "tcp://m15.cloudmqtt.com:18594";
  char [] pass    = "qmaoaTfDebag".toCharArray(); // Fake pass
  String userId   = "oelmanhl";
  String content  = "Hello world!";
  int qos         = 0;


  try {
      MqttClient client = new MqttClient (broker, userId, new MemoryPersistence());
      MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions ();
      options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
      options.setCleanSession(true);
      options.setPassword(pass);          
      System.out.println ("Connecting..."); 

      client.connect(options); 
      System.out.println ("Conntected!");

      MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage ();
      message.clearPayload();
      message.setPayload(content.getBytes());
      message.setQos(qos);
      System.out.println ("Publishing message...");

      client.publish(topic, message);
      System.out.println ("Message published!");

      client.disconnect();
      System.out.println ("Disconect!");

  } catch (MqttException ex) {
      System.out.println ("Reason code: " + ex.getReasonCode());
      System.out.println ("Cause code: " + ex.getCause());
      System.out.println ("Message code: " + ex.getMessage());
  }
  ```

Comment: `Reason code: 5 - Not authorized to perform the requested operation.` It seems you lack the required permissions.

Comment: You have set the password in the options, but not the username (you seam to be using the userid as the clientid (not the same thing)

Comment: Yep! Which ones?

Comment: hardllb - Thanks!